# Flutter Text widget incorrectly wraps Korean text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The Text widget breaks Korean words in the middle - see screenshot.  How can this be fixed?  I tried a bunch of things including changing font family to a Korean font, but nothing worked.  This does not happen with English text, where the lines break along spaces, as expected.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Text('조선시대의 인구 조사에 따르면 조선의 인구는 대체로 700만 명을 넘지 못했다. 조세와 부역 등을 피하려고 호구조사를 기피하는 등 여러 가지 요인으로 40% 가까이 누락되었을 것으로 추측되고');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question, but I think I know your solution so let me know if it worked.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Text("조선시대의 인구 조사에 따르면 조선의 인구는 대체로 700만 명을 넘지 못했다. 조세와 부역 등을 피하려고 호구조사를 기피하는 등 여러 가지 요인으로 40% 가까이 누락되었을 것으로 추측되고", textAlign: TextAlign.center);
```

If it doesn't work, I think that Flutter doesn't understand when a Korean word is seperated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to type a text in Korean, but is it possible for you to reduce using a spacebar? Usually the words will be split based on a spacebar. Therefor, I think refrain from using it might be a help. Sorry if it is not a case.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  Could you rephrase?