# In Flutter, non-english language in Text Widget has strange margin value

Tags: flutter

I'm a developer who just started `flutter`.

While using the `flutter` to configure a screen, I visited to ask about something strange.

I set the `crossAxisAlignment` option to center in the Row widget and set one of the children to Text.

The code is here.

```
child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: 22.0),
          Text(
            'Test',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Then, I created the text in Korean.

The result is the same as the picture below, but as you can see, the upper and lower margins of the letters are slightly different (it is slightly skewed down).

[image]

If this is English, the top and bottom margins are the same as follows.

[image]

This issue is the same for all `Widgets` written in Korean, but does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there might be a similar issue logged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331919/flutter-text-widget-incorrectly-wraps-korean-text).

The proposed solution (although there is no input from OP to indicate it worked), is to pass `textAlign: TextAlign.center` to your `Text` Widget. This might help as `crossAxisAlignment` is a property applied via `Row` and `Column` to their children, whereas `TextAlign` is applied to the `Text` widget directly. Perhaps in conjunction with `crossAxisAlignment` it might produce the desired result.

That or you might want to experiment with padding on the `Text` widget. You can do this by wrapping your `Text` widget in a `Padding` widget or in a `Container` widget. See below.

**Padding**

```dart
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
          child: Text('Padding Via Padding Widget',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22))),
)
```

**Container**

```dart
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
          child: Text('Padding Via Container Widget', 
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this answer, that add textAlign option is not working... So I manually add padding ```EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.5)``` (the padding value "3.5" is just a rough one)

Comment: Did the padding work for you? That was my other suggestion.

Comment: Uh i misunderstood your answer... sorry ;) yes! A text is properly displayed!

Comment: Awesome! Happy or worked